# jQuery Validation plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation plug-in 
is it possible to trow the errors in a specific div?
like

```
<label>userName:</label>
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<span id="userErr">you must enter username</span>
```

is this possible?
10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, as described by [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions). You can use:

```
<label>userName:</label>
<input type="text" name="user"/>
<span class="userErr"></span>

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    // error references a label element, element refers to the invalid element
    element.next('.userErr').append(error);
},
```

or investigate `errorElement`, `wrapper`, and `errorLabelContainer`

Comment: 10x
 but what if i have 2 filed?
can i use the id of the input filed?

Comment: @user186585 - You can use use `<span class="err">` and do `.next('.err')` instead...but the validation plugin already does this exact error placement with a `label`, are you sure you don't want to just change that to a `<span>`? (that's what the `errorElement: 'span'` option would do).